# Swift - Dynamic cast class unconditional?

Tags: ios, generics, swift

It doesn't seem like I can cast a generic type to another? Swift is throwing DynamicCastClassException.

**Basically here is the problem:**

```
// T is defined as T: NSObject
let oebj1 = NetworkResponse<User>()
let oebj2 = oebj1 as NetworkResponse<NSObject>
```

**Here is why I need to do this casting**

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

   // Not allowed to make a generic viewController and therefore have to cast the generic down to NSObject
   func fetchData(completion: (NetworkResponse<NSObject>)->()) {
      fatalError("You have to implement fetchData method")
   }

}

class UsersViewController: BaseViewController  {
    override func fetchData(completion: (NetworkResponse<NSObject>)->()) {
        userNetworkManager.fetchUsers { networkUSerResponse in
            completion(networkUSerResponse as NetworkResponse<NSObject>)
        }
    }
}

class UserNetworkManager {
   func fetchUsers(completion: (NetworkResponse<User>)->()) {
      // Do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `User` a subclass of `NSObject`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yes Generic is defined as ```T: NSObject``` and ```User``` is forced to be a subclass of NSObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.  The basic problem is that `NetworkResponse<NSObject>` and `NetworkResponse<User>` are essentially completely unrelated types that happen to have identical functionality and similar naming.

In this specific case, it really isn't necessary since you're throwing away the known `User`ness of the result anyway, meaning that if you really want to treat it as a `User` later you'll have to do a conditional cast back.  Just remove the generic from `NetworkResponse` and it will all work as expected.  The major drawback is that within `UserVC.fetchData` you won't have access to the returned `User` result without a (conditional) cast.

The alternative solution would be to separate out whatever additional information is in `NetworkResponse` from the payload type (`User`/`NSObject`) using a wrapper of some sort (assuming there's significant sideband data there).  That way you could pass the `NetworkResponse` to super without mutilation and down-cast the payload object as needed.

Something like this:

```
class User : NSObject {
}

class Transaction {
    let request:NSURLRequest?
    let response:NSURLResponse?
    let data:NSData?
}

class Response<T:NSObject> {
    let transaction:Transaction
    let payload:T

    init(transaction:Transaction, payload:T) {
        self.transaction = transaction
        self.payload = payload
    }
}


class UserNetworkManager {
    func fetchUsers(completion: (Response<User>) -> ()) {
        completion(Response(transaction:Transaction(), payload:User()))
    }
}

let userNetworkManager = UserNetworkManager();

class BaseVC {
    func fetchData(completion: (Response<NSObject>) -> ()) {
        fatalError("Gotta implement fetchData")
    }
}

class UserVC : BaseVC {
    override func fetchData(completion: (Response<NSObject>) -> ()) {
        userNetworkManager.fetchUsers { response -> () in
            completion(Response(transaction: response.transaction, payload: response.payload))
        }
    }
}
```

Although at that point, you're probably better off just separating the transaction information and payload information into separate arguments to the callback.

Comment: That's exactly what my current workaround is, but I was hoping I didn't have to separately pass portions of data around