# Swift 2.0 generics type subclass cast

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

There is a base class with generics type:

```
class A<T: AnyObject> {}
```

and a sub class

```
class B: A<NSString> {}
```

and an instance of the sub class:

```
var b = B()
```

The question is: Why

```
b is A             // return false
b is A<AnyObject>  // return false
```

Comment: Are your sure that `b is A` returns `false`? It fails to compile in my test project.

Comment: b is type of `A<NSString>` not `A<AnyObject>`.

Comment: `A<NSString>` and `A<AnyObject>` are *unrelated* types. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/28118440/1187415 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/37190416/1187415 for similar issues with explanations. – Are you asking just out of curiosity or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: As @MartinR says, `b is A` doesn't compile - mainly because you need to supply a type. If you do, e.g. `b is A<NSString>` you get the right answer: `true`. As @ozgur says, you shouldn't be surprised at `b is A<AnyObject>` being `false` - it isn't the same type.

Comment: yes, "b is A" has a compile error.....

Comment: I need to have a array to store all the sub instance of A<T: AnyObject>,